# Как сделать ввод команд и асинхронный вывод в консоль?

Tags: python

Задача в том, чтобы можно было в консоль вводить команды и был асинхронный вывод, то есть, не зависимый от input. Может существуют модули для этой реализации?

Comment: проблема асинхронного вывода в том что он будет бить твою клманду посередь слова. используйте лучше curces какойнибудь